# How to change main content component based on sidebar component in one layout in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie in React js and currently i'm building a layout that contains from many components

For example, a home page layout that contains sidebar component, topbar component, footer component and main content component.

When i click on a link in sidebar component, the main content will be changed based on url of link i clicked on and other components will be same on all pages regardless of url.

Here is my code:

MainLayout.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';  

import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar';
  
const MainLayout = ({children, ...rest}) => {  
  return (  
    <div className="page page-dashboard">  
      {/* <div className="sidebar"><Sidebar></Sidebar></div>   */}
      <div className="main">
        {children}
      </div>  
    </div>  
  )  
}  
  
const MainLayoutRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {  
  return (  
    <Route {...rest} render={matchProps => (  
      <MainLayout>  
          <Component {...matchProps} />  
      </MainLayout>  
    )} />  
  )  
};  
  
export default MainLayoutRoute;
```

MainPage.js

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';  

import  Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import  Header from './Header';
import  Footer from './Footer';

import UsersList from './UsersList';

export default class MainPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
            <div>
              <Header/>
              <Sidebar/>
              <div className="wrapper">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path={"/users"} component={UsersList} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
              <Footer></Footer>
              
            </div>
          </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Sidebar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';  

export default class Sidebar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidenav">
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/users">Users</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/settings">Setting</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          
        );
    }
}
```

UserList.js

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';  

export default class UsersList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
           <button><Link to="/newuser">Add new user</Link></button>
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';  
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './css/custom.scss';

/** Layouts **/  
import LoginLayoutRoute from "./layouts/LoginLayout";  
import MainLayoutRoute from "./layouts/MainLayout";  
  
/** Components **/  
import MainPage from './components/MainPage';  
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage'  

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>  
        <Switch>  
          <Route exact path="/">  
            <Redirect to="/login" />  
          </Route>  
          <LoginLayoutRoute path="/login" component={LoginPage} />  
          <MainLayoutRoute path="/home" component={MainPage} />
        </Switch>  
      </Router>  
    );
  }
 
}
```

But when i refresh the page, it turned blank like this:

[Before i refresh page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F1eV.png)

[After i refresh page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc1J4.png)

How can i fix this ?

Comment: *other components will be same on all pages regardless of url* => could u please explain this line?

Comment: ah ok, i will explain through example. For example: the side bar have a item call user with the url is "/user". When i click on that item, it will be navigated to user page. In the   user page, the default component such as sidebar, topbar, footer will be same as main  layout. That's what i mean

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us, and update your question with details of the specific problem and what you have tried to solve it, and include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we are able to help.

Comment: My app has two layout, the login layout and the main layout. In the main layout, there are some of default components such as sidebar, topbar, footer, main content. When i click on one item in the sidebar, the main content will render component based on the item that i clicked on and also the url like the example i explain above

Comment: **Hope this helps** : http://tszekely.github.io/react-learning-module/step-02

Comment: **One more sample example**  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-sample-project

Comment: @solanki... thanks for your help, i followed the guide in the second link that you gave me and it worked however when i refesh page then it turned blank. How can i fixed this ?

Answer (score 5):

The more direct answer to your question, is **composition**. If you are into reading, here is a good overview:
[Composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

To elaborate further with an example, since no code was provided, I will create some fictitious functional components to demonstrate the process. I also introduced a library that will be used to conduct the routing on the front end called "React Router". For your reference here is a link:
[React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Layout component:

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = (props) => {
return <div>
   <ul>
       <li><Link to={"/home"}>Home</Link></li>
       <li><Link to={"/setting"}>Setting</Link></li>
       <li><Link to={"/payment"}>Payment</Link></li>
  </ul>
  {props.children}
</div>
};
export default Layout;
```

The Layout component will contain the elements shared across the other components. The links, side bar, etc...

The key item from the Layout component is the "props.children". Remember React will do a differential comparison between the virtual dom and the "real" dom to know what parts to replace. So when a link is clicked the "React Router Library" will update the "url" more specifically the path "/home" to "/setting" for example, which will in turn load the component into the content section "props.children".

Finally, in order to connect all the pieces:

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "./Layout";
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Switch,
Route,
Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Setting from "./Setting";
import Payment from "./Payment";

const App = () => {
return <Router>
   <Layout>
       <Switch>
          <Redirect exact={true} from={"/"} to={"/home"}/>
          <Route path={"/home"}><Home/></Route>
          <Route path={"/setting"}><Setting/></Route>
          <Route path={"/payment"}><Payment/></Route>
       </Switch>
   </Layout>
 </Router>
};
export default App;
```

I skipped over the creation of the home/setting/payment components, as they are not critical to the explanation.

The key take from the App component is notice where the "Layout" component is placed "It is wrapping the other components". Remember in the previous section I mentioned that when you click on a link the component will be placed in the content section. Here we defined the routes for each component. The path "/home" equates to the "Home" component, and when the link in the "side bar" for example is clicked, the component "Home" will be loaded, and placed within the "Layout" component, but the Layout elements remain.

Hope this answers your question. Good luck.

---

**Additional clarification to address code added.**

Your App.js file after the modification:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';  
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './css/custom.scss';

/** Layouts **/  
import LoginLayout from "./layouts/LoginLayout";  
import MainLayout from "./layouts/MainLayout";  
  
/** Components **/  
import MainPage from './components/MainPage';  
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage'  

const App = () => {
  return (
      <Router history={history}>  
        <Switch>  
          <Redirect exact={true} from="/" to="/login" />
<Route path="/login" render={() => <LoginLayout><LoginPage/></LoginLayout>}/>
          <MainLayout>
            <Route path="/home" component={MainPage} />
            <Route path={"/users"} component={UsersList} />
          </MainLayout
        </Switch>  
      </Router>  
    );
};

export default App;
```

Your layouts do not need to have routes in them. Just add your routes to the App.js file and wrap the generated route component with the desired layout.

I added the "/users" route in here as well. That should fix your refresh problem.

MainLayout.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';  

import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar';
  
const MainLayout = ({children}) => {  
  return (  
    <div className="page page-dashboard">  
      {/* <div className="sidebar"><Sidebar></Sidebar></div>   */}
      <div className="main">
        {children}
      </div>  
    </div>  
  )  
}  
  
export default MainLayoutRoute;
```

Abstracted the route from the layout component, it does not need to know about it.

MainPage.js

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';  

import  Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import  Header from './Header';
import  Footer from './Footer';

import UsersList from './UsersList';

export default class MainPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
            <div>
              <Header/>
              <Sidebar/>
              <div className="wrapper">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path={"/users"} component={UsersList} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
              <Footer></Footer>
              
            </div>
          </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Seems here you are trying to do multiple things. This to me looks like a Layout component, so perhaps you can remove the code from here and put it into the MainLayout component. Then identify what should go into the MainPage. Just like you are trying to do with the UsersList, it renders content, perhaps the MainPage can display different data?

In the Sidbar.js file:

```
<li><Link to="/settings">Setting</Link></li>
```

This wont work until you create an associated Route in the App.js file, and a Component to render.

In the UserList.js you have the following code:

```
<button><Link to="/newuser">Add new user</Link></button>
```

But you do not have have newuser component. So when you do create a NewUser component, you will also need to add a "Route" as a child to the MainLayout component in the App.js file.

If you notice in the App.js file I imported and created the following for you:

```
import {createBrowserHistory} from "history";
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

And passed it as a prop to the Router:

```
<Router history={history}>
```

In your LoginPage, if you need to redirect after a successful login, you can do the following:

```
import {history} from "../App";
```

Import history from the App Component.

Then in the button's onClick method push "/main" to the stack.

```
<button onClick={() => history.push("/main")}>Login</button>
```

Comment: you can use something like nested routing concept with react-router-dom.

Comment: @Oussama Zeaiter yes, the main content will be changed on the item in the sidebar. Also the item on the sidebar will be render from database. So i need to design a master layout that the main content can be changed flexible based on item in the sidebar

Comment: @BinhNguyenXuan Depending on how you are managing the state of your application, the sidebar component when updates are passed on to it, will re-render itself and display the items.

Comment: So if i want to refresh main layout that has main content render from another component, i should use state, right ?

Comment: @BinhNguyenXuan Not sure I understand what you are asking here. But if you look at the MainLayout component, you notice that it renders children. The children are your various react components, for example your "UserList" component. Furthermore, if you notice in the App component we defined multiple Routes which are wrapped by the MainLayout component. So when the url path matches the route "/users", the UserList component will be rendered inside the MainLayout.